# Can multiple data reporting utilities report on the same uncaught exception?

Tags: android, exception, flurry, acra

My app uses Flurry for analytics and the excellent ACRA for uncaught exception reporting.  This means that there are 3 places uncaught exception reporting happens: Flurry, ACRA and the crash error report within the Android Developer Console.  As far as I can tell, it looks like only one of the 3 areas catches and reports on an exception.  And, more strangely, it seems random as to which one it is.  I.e. sometimes an exception is reported in ACRA, sometimes in Flurry and sometimes in the Developer Console.  I don't have a high enough volume of exceptions (thankfully!) to see any patterns, but ideally I'd like all exceptions at a minimum to go to ACRA.  Am I missing something as to how this works?  Is it possible for all exceptions to go to all 3 reporting places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable Flurry's exception handling using this command in your `onStart()` -

```
FlurryAgent.setCaptureUncaughtExceptions(false);
```

This way it won't interfere with other handlers.

**Update June 2013**

This answer still stands as the way to achieve this goal, but from my experience, Flurry seem to catch an exception here and there in spite of this flag. So it's not a 100% reliable solution.
 Recently I moved to Google Analytics, and turned off the exception handling - and it is perfectly reliable in that respect.

Comment: Thanks uval, that's exactly what I ended up doing.  All exception handling now properly being handled by ACRA.